# Remove a single value from each column randomly from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df something like this,

df

```
    a          b       c            d            e         f
0  Banana    Orange   Lychee     Custardapples Jackfruit  Pineapple
1   Apple    Pear   Strawberry   Muskmelon    Apricot    Peach
2  Raspberry Cherry  Plum           Kiwi        Mango   Blackberry
```

I want to remove a single value from each column randomly.

Eg:

```
        a          b       c            d            e         f
 0    Banana    Orange             Custardapples Jackfruit  
 1               Pear     Strawberry               Apricot    Peach
 2  Raspberry            Plum           Kiwi                Blackberry
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use random `x, y` coordinates and set them to `""`:

```py
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    df.iloc[np.random.randint(df.shape[0]), i] = ""
```

Full code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_clipboard()
print(df)
```

```
           a       b           c              d          e           f
0     Banana  Orange      Lychee  Custardapples  Jackfruit   Pineapple
1      Apple    Pear  Strawberry      Muskmelon    Apricot       Peach
2  Raspberry  Cherry        Plum           Kiwi      Mango  Blackberry
```

for loop for all columns:

```
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    df.iloc[np.random.randint(df.shape[0]), i] = ""
```

```
           a       b       c              d          e           f
0             Orange  Lychee  Custardapples  Jackfruit   Pineapple
1      Apple                      Muskmelon    Apricot            
2  Raspberry  Cherry    Plum                            Blackberry
```

Comment: This removes only value in second column, not in all columns

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pandas` built in method [`Series.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html) with `n=1` argument. I replace the values with `NaN` since that's more elegant:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df[col].sample(n=1).index, col] = np.NaN

           a       b       c              d          e          f
0        NaN     NaN  Lychee  Custardapples  Jackfruit  Pineapple
1      Apple    Pear     NaN      Muskmelon    Apricot      Peach
2  Raspberry  Cherry    Plum            NaN        NaN        NaN
```

If you actually want whitespaces instead, replace `np.NaN` with `''`